# websocket onMessage gets invoked only once in mochajs test

Tags: unit-testing, websocket, mocha.js, chai, faye

```
// global
var ws = null;
var msgCount = 0;
var onMessageHandler = null;

// test #1 - this test passes successfully
describe('connect to wsserver test', function() {
    it('should successfully connect to wsserver', function(done) {
        this.timeout(0);

        ws = new FayeWebSocket.Client('wss://server.com', null, {
            headers: {
                "authToken": "someToken"
            }
        });
        ws.on('open', function() {
            done();
        });
        ws.on('message', function(msg) {
            if (onMessageHandler && typeof onMessageHandler === 'function') {
                onMessageHandler(msg);
            }
        });
        ws.on('close', function(event) {
            console.log('closing websocket!');
        });
        ws.on('error', function(err) {
            console.log("error!: " + err.message);
        });
    });
});

// test #2 - this test blocks indefinitely
describe('send request and get back 3 response messages', function() {
    it('should get back 3 response messages from the wsserver', function(done) {
        this.timeout(0);
        // this function is called ONLY once, although the server is sending 3 messages
        onMessageHandler = function(msg) {
            msgCount++;
            console.log(msg);
            if (msgCount >= 3) {
                done();
            }
        }

        var sendThisRequest = {
            'some': 'json',
            'with': 'some key/value pairs'
        }

        // this line sends a request to the wsserver
        ws.send(JSON.stringify(sendMsg));
    });
});
```

I'm trying to write some basic unit tests to test my websocket apis. These mocha tests are simulating the client, NOT the websocket server.

1. In the first test I just connect to the websocket server using a websocket, this test passes successfully.
2. In the second test I'm sending a request to the server ( from ws.send(message) ), the server does get this request correctly, does some processing and sends **3 websocket messages** to the client. (Looking at the server logs, I can say that this part is working fine on the server)
3. The test should complete after getting the 3 messages and some expect(something).to.equal(something) assertions
4. I haven't been able to figure out so far why the 2nd and 3rd messages are never picked up by the onMessageHandler(). I've tried placing the ws.on('message',function(msg){..}) block at different places in the code but to no avail.

If someone could point me in the right direction for this problem, that would be great. Thanks

Comment: Where your expectation statement?

Comment: Well for now I am just trying to make sure I get the 3 messages, writing the expect() statements could be done later. Do you think that's causing the problem?

Comment: Yes it's streaming. I also added some expect() statements in the handler, still the same problem.

Comment: Can you please share your sample streaming data getting 3 times.

Comment: Not sure how that will help but I'll put the server code once I get to my laptop.

Comment: I can't reproduce with [a simple server](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/8c87b951cd7d4dbff53740313eec2ab1).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not able to do streaming of data with current unit test with mocha.

```
ws.send(JSON.stringify(sendMsg));
```

You are calling this statement only once which means only one time data is streamed. You need to call it multiple time to check `n time streaming`.

Comment: I'm trying to simulate the client, NOT the server. This is my client side code. The client only needs to send 1 message to the server, the server responds with 3 messages. So on the client, ws.send() should happen only once, but the ws.on('message',function(){}) should get executed 3 times for the 3 server response messages.

Comment: can u please add your sever relative srcipt. I setup the same and will check

Answer (score 0):

This code works correctly. There was some problem with the inputs that I was passing to the server. Sorry!